# Strange error (index bound out of array vb.net)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, integer

I am trying to create a list which has 5 elements

```
   Dim clickcount As Integer = 0
   Dim clickindex(6) As Integer
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button5.Click, Button4.Click, Button6.Click
    Dim btn As Button
    btn = CType(sender, Button)

    If btn.BackColor = Color.Red Then
        btn.BackColor = Color.Green
        Dim strList As List(Of Integer) = clickindex.ToList()
        strList.Remove(btn.Tag)
        clickindex = strList.ToArray()
        clickcount -= 1
    ElseIf btn.BackColor = Color.Green Then
        If clickcount = 5 Then
            MsgBox("Max Reach")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        btn.BackColor = Color.Red
        clickcount += 1
        clickindex(clickcount) = btn.Tag

    End If

End Sub
```

Every time a button is clicked,it will add the button number to the list,maximum clicked button is 5
when you click the button again,it will remove button number from the array.

My problem is,when i click several times,error occur,it says Index bound out of array,but the index is still inside the range.
Anyone know where is the problem?

Comment: there's some flaws in this logic... whats the value in `btn.Tag`? Does it ever change?

Comment: i set number inside the btn.tag,example
button1.tag =1
button2.tag =2
it is fixed

Comment: Isn't it possible that `Clickcount`gets negative at some point?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to count how many times each button is clicked? The crash is occurring when you click different red buttons: clickcount becomes negative

Comment: I'm creating a carpark management system,a button represent one carpark place,a user can only select 5 places at once

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Origin of the problem:**

Your problem lies here:

```
    Dim strList As List(Of Integer) = clickindex.ToList()
    strList.Remove(btn.Tag)
    clickindex = strList.ToArray()
```

Take a peek at the following example:
Lets say clickindex looks as follows

```
 clickindex = {1,0,3,0,0,0,0} 'Dim clickindex(6) As Integer declares an array with length '7'
```

After `Dim strList As List(Of Integer) = clickindex.ToList()`, strList is now a `List of Integer` with 7 Items: {1,0,3,0,0,0,0}

```
   strList.Remove(btn.Tag)
   'strList is nog a List of Integer with 6 Items (btn.Tag has been removed)
   clickIndex = lst.ToArray()
   'ClickIndex is now an Array with 6 items instead of the original 7
```

**Possible Solution**

Why not just use the following (more simple) code:

```
Dim clickindex As new List(Of Integer)
   Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click, Button2.Click, Button3.Click, Button5.Click, Button4.Click, Button6.Click
    Dim btn As Button
    btn = CType(sender, Button)

    If btn.BackColor = Color.Red Then
        btn.BackColor = Color.Green
        strList.Remove(btn.Tag)
    ElseIf btn.BackColor = Color.Green Then
        If strList.Count >= 5 Then
            MsgBox("Max Reach")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        btn.BackColor = Color.Red
        strList.Add(btn.Tag)

    End If

End Sub
```